# viewDidAppear, but also when app returns from background

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nsnotificationcenter, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a UIView ("content") that is a white view with a large red dot.

When the app first launches, I want the dot to fade in (just a half sec).

Whenever that view appears again (so, user has been on some other screen and comes back to that screen), I want the dot to fade in.

No problem so far

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
    content.fadeIn()
    }
```

However whenever the app goes to background, when the user brings it to foreground (assuming that view is showing) I want it to fade in.  I do this

```
func weAreActive(notification: NSNotification) {content.fadeIn()}
func weAreNotActive(notification: NSNotification) {content.alpha = 0;}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self, selector: #selector(weAreActive(_:)),
        name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self, selector: #selector(weAreNotActive(_:)),
        name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool)
    {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
```

**First issue**: I'm concerned about using the viewWillAppear/viewDidDisappear **pair** to register/unregister. Am I wrong? Should I be using another **pair** -- perhaps viewDidAppear/somethingElse? Or?

**Second issue**: I'm worried about having both `viewDidAppear` and 'weAreActive` triggered at the same time (perhaps, when the app first launches for instance)

It seems inelegant. Is there a better way to look for "this view genuinely appears" with causes including all of launch, awake, and conventional viewDidAppear?

Comment: I would probably prefer `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` instead.  There are no better events, really. Most times you don't need to change UI when you return from background. Users usually want to work as fast as possible and sometimes they can see a screenshot of the previous UI taken by the system so animations are not a good solution.

Comment: Hi @Sulthan, thanks, what are the reason(s) you prefer `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` for registering/unregistering?

Comment: For this notification it wouldn't probably matter but usually I don't want to get notifications when the view is appearing or disappearing, that's why I would prefer `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First issue:** viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear would be the best places to register/unregister the notifications, for the reason you outlined in your second issue (on first launch, registering *UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification* in viewWillAppear would cause a duplicate animation.

***Edit:*** If you are just checking for when the app returns from background then you should use *UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification* then you can use viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear without having to worry about duplicate calls.

viewDidAppear and viewWillDisappear would be the best places to run the animations so the user will actually get to see them.

**Second Issue:** viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear don't get called when the app returns from background so you don't have to worry about these both being called at the same time.

In some scenarios it would be nice to have an overall 'viewHasDefinitelyAppeared' but there are quite a few instances where you would want them separate, not all apps want users to see animations when they return from background which wouldn't be possible if all the methods where combined in one.

Comment: No problem Joe, (1) in your code example I would say you have it the most sensible way. If you were going to display an animation each time the user leaves the view then I would suggest putting that in **Will** disappear. Your unregistering of the notification makes sense being the final thing that happens. (2) I believe that you don't have to worry about any of them not being called. If they aren't called then that's an issue with Apple. All 4 should get called when an screen is shown or not. I hear what you're saying about the best pair but it really is dependant on what you need to do.

Comment: (i) No sorry, I don't have an Apple doc for that, its from running into that issue a couple times wondering why my viewDidAppear isn't working when I switch back to my app. (ii) I think you will be safe here still because viewWillAppear won't be called early enough to register the notification for the first launch. I am just setting up a test to confirm that but I don't think you have to worry about the double call.

Comment: I stand corrected, viewWillAppear is called early enough and does cause the notification to be called at the beginning. I am going to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: ** UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification** was a particularly good tip - thanks!